# How to show fewer days in Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [this datepicker](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) and as you can see in all demos, the number of days is always the same: 42 (7 days x 6 weeks). Is there any way I could show fewer days? like only 28 (7 days x 4 weeks)?

Comment: It shows 6 rows because some months don't fit in 5. See September 2012, for example. How would you handle that?

Comment: ** EDIT ** Yeap, you're right.. nice example. I think 6 is the min rows, but is there any way I can change it on datepicker?

Comment: Not without substantially rewriting the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use a simple CSS rule to hide the "old" (pre-current month) and "new" (post-current month) days.  I use the terms "old" and "new" because the plugin itself uses these CSS  classes.  So, you could try this:

```
.datepicker table tr td.old, .datepicker table tr td.new { display: none; }
```

This works great for the post-current month values, even removing the extraneous bottom row! But it causes a problem with the pre-current month values and puts the current month's first day always on the first day of the week.

This could be fixed with a small jQuery script that counts the number of `td.old`'s, and may then delete the entire first row (if applicable) and write blank dummy entries for the pre-month days to avoid the issue described above.

I would do it, but busy working on a project.

Answer (score 1):

Josh Padnick, correcting your css code:
Just this:

```
.datepicker table tr td.old, .datepicker table tr td.new { visibility: hidden; }
```